# ¿Cómo evitar que una ruta se guarde en el historial del navegador?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

Lo que quiero hacer es que esta ruta no se guarde en el historial del navegador, ¿alguien sabe cómo?

```js
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
      .when('/news/:id/sponsor',{
        templateUrl: 'html/sponsor.html',
        controller: 'sponsorCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'sponsor',
        title: 'Patrocinador',

        // Tal vez con una función en "resolve:{}", no?
        resolve: {

        }

      });
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
  }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Técnicamente hablando no puedes evitar que lo guarde, lo que puedes es **reemplazar** la url actual con la nueva dando impresión que nunca se navegó. Así cuando presione atrás no navegará de nuevo a esa url sino a la primera.

En lugar de

`url1 -> url2 -> url3`

Tendrías

`url1 ->` <s>`url2`</s> `-> url3`

Por lo que la `url2` no queda registrada.

Esto sólo lo puedes hacer por código usando el método `replace` del servicio [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location).

Aquí hay un ejemplo

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/url1', {
        template: '<h1>Esta es una página de prueba</h1><h2>url1</h2><p>Presionar atrás en url3 debería retornar directamente a esta página</p><p>Haga <a href="#/url2">click</a> para continuar</p>'
      })
      .when('/url2', {
        template: '<h1>Página a eliminar</h1><h2>url2</h2><p>Haga <a class="sample" ng-click="eliminaHistorial()">click</a> para continuar</p>',
        controller: 'HistorialCtrl'
      })
      .when('/url3', {
        template: '<h1>Ultima página</h1><h2>url3</h2><p>Haga <a class="sample" ng-click="goBack()">click</a> para simular el back del navegador</p>',
        controller: 'BackCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/url1'
      });
  })
  .controller('HistorialCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.eliminaHistorial = function() {
      $location.path('/url3').replace();
    }
  })
  .controller('BackCtrl', function($scope, $window) {
    $scope.goBack = function() {
      $window.history.back();
    };
  });
```

```css
a,
a.sample {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias @devconcept